# User properties are not set in google analytics (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I would like to send the user_id as a user property to GA4 so every event will also contain the identifier of my user.

This is what my tag configuration looks like :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1Lo0.png)

This is what dlv - user_id looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFaDJ.png)

and this is how the code looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjn1O.png)

I can clearly see that the event is fired in the analytics debug view
and I can also see that the custom parameter that I sent is pushed to GA4 (data_dim)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYBPo.png)

However, when I look at the user properties it looks empty.
I expect to see there the user_id that I'm setting.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1y0R.png)

What am I missing ?

Thx
Sagi

However, when I look at the user properties it looks empty.
I expect to see there the user_id that I'm setting.